# SQL - Comparing Multiple Rows in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a pricing table for a retail software that holds a UPC for an item, a property code (i.e. "REGULAR_PRICE, PROMO_PRICE"), and a price.

example table:

```
400000320243 REGULAR_PRICE 80
400000320243 PROMO_PRICE 80
400000320250 REGULAR_PRICE 50
400000320250 PROMO_PRICE 40
```

I am trying to write a query to find where the PROMO_PRICE = REGULAR_PRICE for any UPCs and output a list of the UPCs where this condition holds.

I cannot figure out how to write this in SQL.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Attempted pseudo code:

```
for each upc:
  if upc.regular_price = upc.promo_price:
      print upc
```

Comment: Are promo and regular in separate tables?

Comment: No, they are in the same table.

Answer (score 5):

You could do that a bunch of ways.  One way is to create two sets, one with upcs and regular prices, the other with upcs and promo prices, and join those two sets, like this:

```
select r.upc, r.price from
   (select upc, price from t where propertyCode = 'regular_price') r inner join
   (select upc, price from t where propertyCode = 'promo_price') p on
   r.upc = p.upc and
   r.price = p.price
```

You can try it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc32f/2).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're table is named `Pricing` and you have columns named `upc`, `propertycode`, and `price`, you could perform a self join on this data. It would look something like:

```
SELECT Reg.upc
FROM Pricing Reg JOIN Pricing Promo ON Reg.upc = Promo.upc
WHERE Reg.propertycode = 'REGULAR_PRICE' 
    AND Promo.propertycode = 'PROMO_PRICE'
    AND Reg.price = Promo.price
```

Comment: I don't think that will run on MS Sql Server 2008 R2. What is `USING` ? Can be fixed like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc32f/4

Comment: @zespri ahh, yes. I didn't realize that MS SQL Server didn't have the USING construct. It's a simplififed syntax for equi-joins (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Equi-join). I'll edit my question to add that in.

Answer (score 1):

An [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) query will also work here:

```
SELECT upc, price
FROM atable
WHERE property_code = 'REGULAR_PRICE'
INTERSECT
SELECT upc, price
FROM atable
WHERE property_code = 'PROMO_PRICE'
;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc32f/5) (uses @Beth's schema).

Answer (score 0):

In addition... Judging by your example - looks like a table to me - you may use LAG() / LEAD() analytic functions if available in you version of SQL to compare data - prev or next row with current row values...

Comment: FYI, LAG() / LEAD() analytic functions available in SQLServer2012

Answer (score 0):

Option with [EXISTS subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test3 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test3 t2
              WHERE t2.PriceName = CASE WHEN t1.PriceName = 'PROMO_PRICE' THEN 'REGULAR_PRICE'
                                        WHEN t1.PriceName = 'REGULAR_PRICE' THEN 'PROMO_PRICE' END
                AND t1.Price = t2.Price                                                    
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/616cc/1/0)